# 802.11p FSM received an unknown event when in TRANSMITFRAME state

Tags: omnet++, veins, 802.11p

I am currently doing vanets simulation with Veins 2.0-rc1, my network stack use the 802.11p class as a mac layer.

I am receiving the current error: 802.11 FSM received an unkown event. I looked for the associated event and mac state related to this error and found that the error occurs under TRANSMITFRAME_4 state after receiving an event like EV_BROADCAST_RECEIVED.

1. how can i fix this error ?
2. what is generating this error ?

I am joining to this post a diagramm of the current FSM and a link to the 802.11p c++ class.

Many thanks,

[image: 802.11p FSM diagramm]
[802.11p c++ class](https://github.com/Arslan90/mixim/blob/master/mixim/src/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac80211p.cc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins 2.0-rc1 was still using the MiXiM 802.11 FSM, which had some issues. Since then, many bugs have been found and the MAC layer has been rewritten for improved stability and speed. If you can, upgrade to a more recent version (like Veins 2.2).

A larger change (though likely still very worthwhile) would be to upgrade to one of the even later releases like Veins 3 or Veins 4. This would also allow you to use more recent versions of SUMO, for which several bugs have been fixed since the version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so maybe i am prone to error due to bugs with FSM ? Especially when receiving a broadcast event and the mac layer is in transited frame state

Comment: I don't exactly recall which conditions triggered bugs in the FSM, but I know that we received bug reports semi-frequently, which is why we decided to write our own.